# jQuery Form data not submitted

Tags: jquery, forms, upload

I am trying to submit form data with jQuery but it is showing some strange behavior. Let me explain what is mean by "strange".
If I use the HTML code below:

```
<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="myfile" id="myfile" />
</form>
```

and this jQuery code:

```
$("#myfile").bind("change",function() {
    var data = $('form#upload').serialize();
        alert(data);
});
```

It shows the expected result but if I change the HTML code to:

```
<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile" />
</form>
```

It simply does not show anything. I've also tried `FormData()` instead of `serialize()` but same result. I've also tried reading data on server-side but it also shows the same.
I'm Using PHP as server-side language.

Comment: Files aren't stored in form data, they're stored in the `Request` object when the server is hit.

Comment: @mattytommo you mean I've to use `$_REQUEST` on server side??

Comment: Apologies, I was referring to C#, in PHP, use `$_FILES`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file element is a bit different from others. To submit file in js, you  have to use different way. You can use plugin like : 
[jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Comment: But we can use `FormData()` to handle files too see [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax) about it which clearly shows it. And so does [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData)

Comment: Yes, but you aren't cross browsers. Can you post your FormData code? To use FormData, you don't have to just replace serialize by formData, you have to implement a new FormData... like showed in the link you post

Comment: I'm using the latest Google Chrome version and this is what happening in it.

Comment: `var formData = new FormData($('form#upload')[0]);
     alert(formData);
     $.ajax({
      url: '../uploader.php',
      type: 'POST',
      xhr: function() {
       myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
       if(myXhr.upload){
        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progress, false);
       }
       return myXhr;
      },
      beforeSend: beFore,
      success: Okay,
      error: err,
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
     });`